# Opencv for python 3.5.2

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.5

We seem to be running into a problem downloading `opencv` which is a dependency for gym-gazebo. Seems `opencv` works for Python 2.7 but gym-gazebo requires Python 3.5.

We tried fixing it by going into the bash file and tweeking a bit with Python path. We got to a point where `opencv` can be imported but `rospy` which is an essential module won't get imported.

We have this error :

```
ImportError: /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_Type
```

Any advice?

Comment: You might want to add information about your operating system and how you installed opencv.

Answer (score 1):

Python modules with binary code need to be built for the specific python version.

Install opencv for python 3.5 using whatever python package manager is on your system (conda / pip etc).

If you are on windows you might want to bookmark  [Unofficial python builds](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)